# Setup FTP access to specific directory on Azure VM

Tags: azure, iis, ftp, virtual-machine, endpoint

I've setup a virtual machine on Azure. I have installed on it an apache LAMP setup. I've also setup an endpoint for FTP with the following details:

```
Name: FTP
Protocol: TCP
Public port: 21
Private port: 21
```

Now I am able to FTP into the root of my server and from there navigate to where web files are kept.

```
Host: xxxx.cloudapp.net
Usename: azureuser
Password: xxxxxxxx
```

The password is my root user password.

In my server I have multiple websites hosted. The vhosts setup routes domains to the relevant directories. Now I have a client that wants FTP access to their website. I obviously can't give them my global access. How do I setup a new FTP user that only has access to a specific directory?

Comment: What FTP Server are you using?

Comment: @JoeRaio currently it works with my Azure assigned cloudapp.net address so xxxxxxx.cloudapp.net